# JavaScript - delete all get parameters from URL in address bar without reloading the page

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to clear all GET parameters from the URL in the browsers address bar without initiating a page reload?

I tried to remove all GET prematers and then fake a page reload and immediatelly interrupt it as a workaround, but this does not replace the URL.

```
window.location.href = window.location.href.replace(window.location.search,'');
window.stop();
document.execCommand('Stop');
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Comment: what are you hoping to accomplish by removing them?

Comment: I need to remove them on a specific page on my site because they trigger a download everytime when I reload the page with a specific get parameter set. Explain how this is a xy problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

get the base url without parameters

```
baseUrl = window.location.href.split("?")[0];
```

then setting the url inside the address bar

```
window.history.pushState('name', '', baseUrl);
```